# get content of the last modified file of a directory as txt in php

Tags: php, filesystems

consider this is my directory and has multiple .txt file
$Directory = './downloads';

I want to store the content of last modified file in the directory to a variable or something like that.
that I can use somewhere else as a txt file

`$Directory = './testlog'; $downloads = scandir($Directory , 1); $reportFile =   $filesInTestLog [0] ; $finalReportFile = $reportFile . '.txt';`

but it just pick the name of the file not the content`

Comment: `file_get_contents` already invented.

Comment: By reading the comments you got, instead of just repeating what you want once more?

Comment: Once you've got the filename, use readFile() or file_get_contents() to output its contents. This is not secret information, have you done any research yet?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the files from the directory and check which file has the newest modification time with function filemtime(), then read the content of the file and store it as a variable.

I think that is somehow the simplest way of approaching this.